# Chartjs xaxis labels auto decrease disabled

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I used chartjs bar chart. It's for one year 52 week's based data show. So xaxis labels are 52.

And I will use `option.responsive = true` for my chart fixed width & height.

But the chartjs is auto hide some xaxis label. **I need to disable auto hide some xaxis label option**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use autoSkip option it's a possible way. For ex:

`options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.autoSkip = false`

(or)

```
options: {
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            maxRotation: 90,
            minRotation: 90
         }
      }]
   }
}
```

Ref to : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/?h=autoskip